# add tags in s3 objects without replacing the existing one using ruby

Tags: ruby, object, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, tagging

Could you please help me to add extra tags without replacing or modifying the existing one using ruby on rails.

s3.put_object_tagging(
bucket: bucket,
key: key,
version_id: version,
tagging: {tag_set: [{key: tag_key, value: status}]}
)

This code replaces the existing tags in the object.